# Removing object from ArrayList

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, instance

I have written my own class called `Person` with the variables `String name`, `int age` and `double height`, as well as a `toString()`. I have then created an `ArrayList` of `Person`s, and added a couple of instances. It prints well. Now I want to write a method that, when I write a name, checks the `ArrayList` for instances with that name, an if so, removes that instance. How should I do this?

Here is what I've written:

```
import java.util.*;
public class PersonManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        people.add(new Person("Adam ", 29, 177.5));
        people.add(new Person("Bernadette", 19, 155.2));
        people.add(new Person("Carl", 45, 199));

        for (Person p : people)
            System.out.println(p);

        System.out.println("Select person to remove");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();


        // if there is a person with that name in the list, that
        //person gets removed from the list

    }

}
```

Comment: How do you think you should do it?

Comment: Looks like you already know how to loop through an `ArrayList.` What do you know about comparing two `String` objects?

Comment: Take a look at the methods of `ArrayList`, see what the opposite of `add` might be and give it a try. If it doesn't work, show what you tried and we can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JAVA 8 and don't mind of creating a new List from the original you can use JAVA 8 stream like that :

```
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

    people.add(new Person("Adam ", 29, 177.5));
    people.add(new Person("Bernadette", 19, 155.2));
    people.add(new Person("Carl", 45, 199));
    String nameToRemove = "name";
    people = people.stream().filter((t) -> !t.getName().equals(nameToRemove)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

As @MasterMind said: if you have access to JDK 8 features, you can either use filtering (as shown in his example) or alternatively, use the new `Collection#removeIf(..)` method. In your case, that would be something like:

```
people.removeIf(person -> person.getName().equals(name));
```

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbFNMem9MMXlXUUE) for a fully working example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to navigate to `Person` with given name and remove it from the list.
So you can use iterator while going through list:

```
Iterator personIter = people.iterator();
while(personIter.hasNext()){
    Person p = (Person)personIter.next();    
    if(name != null && name.equals(p.getName())){
        personIter.remove();
        break; //will prevent unnecessary iterations after match has been found
    }
}
```